# Laravel Why pivot table is empty?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, laravel

I have a simple relationship in laravel eroquent

Here is the bidders table creation

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('bidders', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('params_name');
        $table->string('params_value');
        $table->string('bidder_name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Here is `bidder_parameter` table creation

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('bidder_parameters', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('bidder_id');
        $table->foreign('bidder_id')->references('id')->on('bidders')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Here is a bidder model

```php
class Bidder extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'bidders';

    protected $fillable = [
        "params_name",
        "params_value",
        "bidder_name"
    ];

    public function page()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Page');
    }

    public function parameters()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\BidderParameter');
    }
}
```

and here is `BidderParameter` model

```php
class BidderParameter extends Model
{
    public function parameters()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Bidder');
    }
}
```

Here is parameter controller for inserting data to database

```php
public function store(Request $request){
        // dd($request);
        if($request->ajax())
        {
            $rules = array(
                'params_name.*'  => 'required',
                'params_value.*'  => 'required',
                'bidders_name.*' => 'required'
            );
            $error = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
            if($error->fails())
            {
                return response()->json([
                    'error'  => $error->errors()->all()
                ]);
            }
            $params_name = $request->params_name;
            $params_value =$request->params_value;
            $bidders_name =$request->bidders_name;
            for($count = 0; $count < count($params_name); $count++)
            {
                $data = array(
                    'params_name'   => $params_name[$count],
                    'params_value'  => $params_value[$count],
                    'bidders_name'  => $bidders_name[$count],
                );

                $insert_data[] = $data; 
                // dd($insert_data);

            }
            Bidders:insert($insert_data);
            return response()->json([
                'success'  => 'Data Added successfully.'
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Now when I submit data to the database 'bidders table`have data saved into it but`bidder_parameter`  is empty

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: What exactly is the `bidder_parameters` table for? Currently it only holds a reference to `bidder_id`, no "useful" other fields?!

Comment: Your migration and models look fine at a glance, but if the issue is happening when you're inserting data, you probably should include that code. Edit: Hindsight, if `bidder_parameters` is supposed to be a `pivot` between `bidders` and `parameters`, you shouldn't have a model for it, and you'll need a migration/model for `parameters`/`Parameter`

Comment: The structure you're exposing in your question does not use a pivot table. it's just a one to many relation. Please add the insertion in DB code, you're issue is there. Nothing is wrong with what you showed till now.

Comment: This looks like a 1 to many, not a many to many. Laravel has you define many to many by both parent models having `belongsToMany` relationship methods. You will need to create an intermediate table that by default will be named alphabetically: `model1_model2` with an `id`, `model1_id` and `model2_id`

Comment: @N69S I have added insertion code , check the update

Comment: @user9964622 i dont understant what you want to put in the `bidder_parameters` table. What you are doing is inserting in the `bidders` table.

Comment: I know this topic is not under discussion but your code structure is not good. Controller is only an agent to transfer request and data to and from database and front-end.

Apply OOP and use SOLID princliples as well

Answer (score 1):

Many to many relationship contains 3 tables. 2 tables are main and 3rd table is combination of those 2 tables' primary keys.

**For example**

User can have many roles

and

Role can belong to many users

so that requires many to many relationship

So we need a database schema like this:

1. `Users table -> (id, name ,...) e.g. Jonn Doe with id 1`
2. `Roles table -> (id, name, ...)  e.g. SUPER_ADMIN with 1`
3. `role_user table (id, user_id, role_id)` `role_id` is foreign key of `roles table` and `user_id` is foreign key of `users table`

Now in Model classes:

```
In  User Model

public function roles(){
   return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class,'role_user','user_id','role_id');
}
```

Now in Roles class

```
public function users(){
   return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'role_user','role_id','user_id');
   //note keys are in opposite order as in roles() method
}
```

Now you can call function from `User` instance and `Role` instance where you want

```
$user->roles // as collection
$user->roles() // as eloquent instance
```

Also

```
$role->users // as collection
$role->users() // as eloquent instance
```

You can read more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)